# Display JSON data with Django/ Python and Bootstrap

Tags: json, django, nested

I want to display data from a countries API (JSON format) into a bootstrap 5 card inside a Django project. The JSON file contains dictionaries and lists. I can access data to use a for loop. For example x.capital.0 displays the capital for all the countries. But the currencies is the problem because it is a nested dictionary. I could use `x.currencies.USD.name` but then I have to specify the second key (USD) for every country so the I have to use 100 lines of code the do this. Is there a way to skip the second key? I tried `x.currencies.itmes()`, `x.currencies.values()`, `x.currencies[1]` and much more.

Could you please help to solve this problem.

Github: https://github.com/Roelof132/countries-app/blob/main/space/templates/home.html

API: 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all'

For the API also see the views.py file.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use pandas.

```
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
```

Do whatever you want with the dataframe data

Once you have the final dataframe you can pass it into the context

```
    context={
             'df':df.to_html(table_id="df",justify='center'),
            }
```